# What''s the "earliest" place one can set an environment variable during Linux boot process?

Tags: login, environment-variables, posix

I know I can set a variable in a shell startup file, but the thing is, I am trying to set up a POSIX-compatible environment, and a POSIX shell does not parse any startup files other than the one specified by the environment variable `ENV`. This presents a problem - currently my `login` starts the shell as `bash`, which I will try to replace with `sh` so Bash runs as POSIX shell - however then it will not parse the default startup files and I need `ENV` set to specify these. Which means as far as I understand that I need to specify `ENV` **before** `login` starts the shell, correct?

Now, how would I do that? I hope my question is clear, if not I will gladly redact it.

Comment: Try adding `ENV= ` to the kernel command line.  You would have to edit this in *grub* or whatever bootloader is used.

Comment: I did, but the variable doesn't show up in any shell and is not even listed under any of the relevant processes (`init`, `systemd-*`, `login`, `agetty`) when inspecting `/proc/$pid/environ`. I too thought that was the solution, but it didn't work. I am suspecting that the variable is passed to the kernel, however it is supressed/removed shortly thereafter.